# In WPF, is there a way to set foreground of Button when a general Textblock style with foreground exists?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, user-interface, .net-core

In my App.xaml file I have the following style defined:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

This code impacts the foreground of all buttons in other xaml files.

In a place it looks like this

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Foreground="Yellow" Content="I want to be yellow" Width="200" Height="100"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I would expect the text of the button to be yellow here but the style from the app.xaml takes over and makes it blue...

[image]

There seems to be no way of overriding this for the button (without re-writing the Control Template). Is that really true or have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's good article about problem you're facing https://ikriv.com/dev/wpf/TextStyle/TextBlockStyle

It sums up to

> Implicit TextBlock style will affect all buttons and other content controls in our application, and it is not practical to rewrite them all to contain explicit content definition. The best way is to leave implicit TextBlock style alone, and apply a style with desired properties to the top-level windows. The properties will then be inherited by the text blocks in a less dramatic way.

Comment: Great article! This makes sense to me now. I will try to get rid of the implicit TextBlock style! Thanks!